# How to play video using JMF from byte array in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, video, jframe, jmf

I am trying to run video from existing byte array (mp4 file) in JFrame (Java Swing). Byte array is saved in MongoDb.

I found that I can create Player instance by Manager.createRealizedPlayer (mediaURL), but I have only bytearray, not URL. Also I tried a lot of sample code how to run it in JFrame, but unsuccessfully.

Is there anybody, who can send me sample code to run movie from byte array and run it in JFrame of Swing?

Comment: Can you play an MP4 from URL (or file. or ..anything)?  AFAIU, JMF does not [support MP4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) in ***any*** form.  BTW - you do realize that JMF was abandoned ..must be a decade ago now.

Comment: No I am trying to play file from hard drive - unsuccessfully. If JMF was abandoned, how can I run mp4 in Java swing from byte array otherwise?

Comment: I found this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTQ1b3-TUI4, using vlcj, I will try it tomorrow. Hope it helps.

Comment: So I solved it by the tutorial from above link. Is necessary to have the same version of jdk and VLC libs, thanks.